# Dock shown both at bottom and left in Activities overview / search window

Tags: gnome-shell, customization, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10. I have installed ***Dash to dock*** gnome extension. But when i click on *Activities* button, two docks are shown. One at the bottom and one at the left. I want to see only at the bottom.
Is there a way to remove the left dock??
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It was happening only when I pressed *Activities* button. But after restart of computer it is working properly. Thank You..

Comment: Check with Gnome tweaks anyway. Ubuntu Dock sometimes has the quirk to appear after a change of extensions. Turning it on and then back off in Tweaks sets things properly back to normal.

Comment: I used the same technique. But worked for only some time, even ubuntu dock started showing at lock screen. So, I just removed Ubuntu Dock